# 100% CPU usage after logstash install

Tags: ubuntu, logstash

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-and-visualize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial to install a software stack Logstash/ES/Kibana on my Ubuntu server. I changed logstash configuration to test everything locally before trying to ship logs. So I have a single node running ES/Kibana and Logstash configured as follow :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/syslog"
    type => "syslog"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

Everything is working as intended from what I can see on Kibana, but I have a background process that eats 100% cpu. Top tells me it's a job in java running under logstash user. `sudo service logstash stop` does not stop the process from running. I've also tried to remove web service following [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/logstash-users/cgOIqxr_J4g), without success.

Answer (score 22):

Digital Ocean's tutorial uses *nginx* in front of *Kibana* and listens on port 80. *logstash* ships with *logstash-web* that also wants to listen to port 80.

Since *Ubuntu* uses *upstart*, trying to kill the java processes won't succeed as they will keep respawning according to `/etc/init/logstash*.conf`. The high CPU usage comes from the fact that *logstash* uses a lot of CPU time at startup and should calm down after a couple of seconds, but because it dies being unable to bind to port 80 and keeps respawning, it looks as if it's constantly using resources.

If you have the same problem as I did, look at *logstash*'s *PID*s and you will notice they change. You should also see `Address already in use - bind - Address already in use` at the end of `/var/log/logstash/logstash.log`.

So, we just need to disable *logstash-web*. On *Ubuntu*, this can be done with:

> $ echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/logstash-web.override

To stop *logstash-web* without rebooting, we use

> $ sudo stop logstash-web

Comment: Apparently I didn't notice OP's link that has the same instructions to disable logstash-web. Sorry about that. Maybe my answer can still help debugging the problem.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. It was killing my system with the all the four cores of the cpu being used at almost 100%. Finally, I had to uninstall logstash.

Comment: @ajay Did you notice the same behavior with PIDs and got the same message in the log?

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the logstash processes using `skill -u logstash`. Run logstash in the foreground with increased verbosity.

If you change (temporarily) the output to be just a stdout output, what do you notice?

Note that if you'll likely get communication with other nodes; saying `host => localhost` doesn't mean that you just get communication with port `9300` (I suggest testing with `tcpdump` on the `lo` and `eth0` (or whatever is appropriate). So check your firewall, and perhaps take the firewall down temporarily.

Also note that `localhost` may be giving you a IPv6 result; you may like to say `127.0.0.0` instead.

The documentation the elasticsearch output can be seen at [logstash docs](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/elasticsearch)

You don't say if you're using the embedded elasticsearch or not; the default is false, so I guess you are not.

I do recall having an issue in my own deployment where logstash and elasticsearch were present on the same host, and there was a collision for port 9300; I resolved that by having logstash use port `9301` (bind_port).

I suggest that you should also set the 'cluster'. The default 'protocol' will be 'node', which means it will try to become part of the cluster (not a data-node though), you could trying changing this to 'transport' or `http` and observe behavior change.

I found it very useful to look at the network traffic carefully when I was starting out in order to carefully validate the behavior.

FWIW, I found the 'Logstash Book' very worthwhile (and cheap).